# extract names in custom <h2> but It is extracted many times beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract names in custom `<h2>`, but the names I want are extracted many times.
how to fix this problem and extract it one time
The page I am pulling data from
[here](https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/motor-vehicle-accidents/texas/houston/page1/)

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest
lawy_name = []
page_num = 1
phone = []
logo = []
website = []
links = []
while True:
    try:
        result = requests.get(f"https://example.com/motor-vehicle-accidents/texas/houston/page{page_num}/")
        src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
        page_limit = int("126")
        if(page_num > page_limit // 25):
            print("page ended, terminate")
            break
        lawy_names = soup.select('div.poap.serp-container.lawyer h2.indigo_text')
        for i in range(len(lawy_names)) :
            lawy_name.append(lawy_names[i].text.strip())
            links.append(lawy_names[i].find("a").attrs["href"])
        for link in links:
            result = requests.get(link)
            src = result.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
            phones = soup.find("a", {"class":"profile-phone-header profile-contact-btn"})
            phone.append(phones["href"])
            logos = soup.find("div", {"class":"photo-container"})
            logo.append(logos.find('img')['src'])
            websites = soup.find("a", {"class":"profile-website-header","id":"firm_website"})
            website.append(websites.text.strip())

        page_num +=1
        print("page switched")
    except:
        print("error")
        break
    
file_list = [lawy_name, phone, website, logo]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)
with open("/Users/dsoky/Desktop/fonts/Moaaz.csv", "w") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(["lawyer name","phone","website","logo"])
    wr.writerows(exported)
```

Problem:

[image: problem preview]

Comment: Have you tried not using a while True loop?

Comment: I removed it and same problem

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts, including your own.

Comment: Something went wrong while trying to write something down

Comment: The URL is sort of integral to your post and problem, and you link to it outside the code. It's also publicly available for anyone to see in the revision history. There is no point in trying to hide evidence of which URL it was. It also doesn't fall under a PII or PHI category that would warrant true redaction by moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website does produce a lot of duplicate entries. You could probably assume that all entries have unique names, as such a dictionary could be used to hold all of your data. Simply skip any entries for which you have already seen the same name. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

lawyers = {}
page_num = 1

while True:
    print(f"Page {page_num}")
    req = requests.get(f"https://example.com/motor-vehicle-accidents/texas/houston/page{page_num}/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    found = False
    
    for id in ['sponsored_serps', 'ts_results', 'poap_results', 'basic_results']:
        div_results = soup.find('div', id=id)
    
        if div_results:
            for result in div_results.find_all('div', class_='lawyer'):
                name = result.h2.get_text(strip=True)
                
                if name not in lawyers:
                    print(' ', name)
                    link = result.h2.a['href']
                    req_details = requests.get(link)
                    soup_details = BeautifulSoup(req_details.content, "lxml")

                    a_phone = soup_details.find("a", {"class":"profile-phone-header profile-contact-btn"}, href=True)
                    
                    if a_phone:
                        phone = a_phone['href']
                    else:
                        phone = None
                    
                    div_logo = soup_details.find("div", {"class":"photo-container"})
                    
                    if div_logo.img:
                        logo = div_logo.img['src']
                    else:
                        logo = None
            
                    a_website = soup_details.find("a", {"class":"profile-website-header","id":"firm_website"})
                    
                    if a_website:
                        website = a_website.get_text(strip=True)
                    else:
                        website = None
                    
                    lawyers[name] = [phone, logo, website]
                    found = True
                    
    # Keep going until no new names found
    if found:
        page_num += 1
    else:
        break

with open('Moaaz.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Name', 'Phone', 'Logo', 'Website'])
    
    for name, details in lawyers.items():
        csv_output.writerow([name, *details])
```

Comment: Just change the starting `page_num` to 1. It was just a test to ensure it stopped.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful work. Can you add a simple modification so that fix this problem  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dsoky\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 31, in <module>
    logo = div_logo.find('img')['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
PS C:\Users\dsoky>

Comment: He extracted it to page 4 and this problem appeared to me
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\dsoky\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 31, in <module>
     logo = div_logo.find('img')['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Ah yes, some of the entries have missing items. I've added some extra checks. You might need to investigate those further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241495/discussion-between---and-martin-evans).